# Como criar um reenvio de email apos 30 dias?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu estou criando um reenvio de email, preciso que ele funcione da seguinte maneira, quero que consulte a tabela e verifique todos os emails, se for menor do que 30 dias reenvia o email. Eu tenho esse código abaixo onde antes estava funcionando, mas o primeiro email maior de 30 dias que é encontrado reenvia o email pra ele e os outros não envia  kkkkk. Alguém poderia me ajudar? desde já agradeço.

```html
<?php
#dados para conexão com banco de dados 
$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','integracao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$search = mysqli_query($strcon,"SELECT * FROM tb_emprestimo WHERE DATA >= '(date_sub(curdate(), interval 30 day))'");
$linha =mysqli_fetch_array($search);
$emailDestino = $linha["EMAIL"];
$destinatario = $linha["NOME_PESSOA"];
if(@mysqli_num_rows($search) > 0){
 
// Caminho da biblioteca PHPMailer
require 'phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

// Instância do objeto PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;

// Configura para envio de e-mails usando SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

// Servidor SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

// Usar autenticação SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

// Usuário da conta
$mail->Username = '********@gmail.com';

// Senha da conta
$mail->Password = '********';

// Tipo de encriptação que será usado na conexão SMTP
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

// Porta do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = 465;

// Informa se vamos enviar mensagens usando HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

// Email do Remetente
$mail->From = '*********@gmail.com';
// Nome do Remetente
$mail->FromName = 'ZINA PORTO';

// Endereço do e-mail do destinatário
$mail->addAddress($emailDestino);

// Assunto do e-mail
$mail->Subject = 'Assunto';

// Mensagem que vai no corpo do e-mail
$mail->Body = '<h2>Olá, '.$destinatario.'</h2>
<p> MENSAGEM PARA DESTINATARIO</p>';
   
}

?>
```

Comment: No título vc diz "_após 30 dias_" e no texto "_se for menor do que 30 dias reenvia o email_"... e no código vc usa o operador `>=`.... No código irá pegar os registros com 30 dias ou mais. Ficou confuso pra saber o objetivo devido às contradições de informações.

Comment: Eu quis dizer se a data que estiver no banco for menor do que a data de hoje. Ex: Está no banco 01/03/2019, essa é menor do que data de hoje 28/04/2019, consequentemente tem mais de 30 dias. Sendo assim tem que enviar o email. Estou certo?entendeu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para retornar apenas os registros onde a coluna `DATA` (assumindo que a coluna seja do tipo `date` ou `datetime`) possua uma data igual ou anterior a 30 dias da data atual, você deveria usar o operador `<=` (menor ou igual) e não `>=` (maior ou igual) e com a função `date_sub()` fora das aspas simples:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_emprestimo WHERE DATA <= date_sub(curdate(), interval 30 day)
```

Isso significa que irá pegar apenas as datas ANTERIORES (menores) a 29 dias pra trás (menor ou igual a 30), sem contar a data atual.

Se hoje são 29/04, irá pegar qualquer data anterior a 31/03, porque do dia 30/03 até 29/04 são exatos 30 dias.

Comment: mano não funcionou. não esta acontecendo nada. você acha que esse codigo de disparo de email esta correto feito dessa forma. você tem alguma sujestão de como posso fazer?

Comment: Mas está encontrando os registros?

Comment: Mano eu fui dar uma olhada direito no meu Banco, a coluna data e TIMESTEMP. Vou corregir aqui e retorno.